# Unable to set up Python2 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2013 and I am trying to setup Python in VS-2013.

I downloaded the tools for Python directly from visual studio (I was prompted by Visual Studio with the links to install that). But when I downloaded and installed Python, it installed Python 3.6 for me.

However the version 3.6 is not compatible with VS-2013 and error says "Python 3.6 is not compatible with VS-2013". Then I manually downloaded and installed Python 2.2, but this is still not integrated automatically with VS-2013. The error now says "You have not any interpreter".

How do I resolve this?

Comment: do you have python on your system `PATH`?

Comment: how to add it to the path? I think it should automatically added to the path.. Because when i install python 3.6 through the link VS-2013 provide me,it added to path because code is interpreting but error says  python 3.6 is not compatible with VS-2013. When i uninstall and download python 2.2 error says u have not install interpreter.

Comment: check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)

Comment: Consider just using "VS Code", it works with Python 3. That said, 2.2 is completely inacceptably outdated for any new development. Even 2.7 shouldn't be used for new stuff, in particular learning the language.

Comment: from where i can get the path?

Comment: The default path should be something like `c:\python[ver]` e.g. `c:\python27` I suppose.

Comment: Yes i found it thanks

Comment: I tried alot, i added it to the path from enironment variables but still it is saying you have not any interpreter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed Python correctly, by checking the result when you write 'python' on command prompt.

You should also be sure that to add python to the PATH variable, which you can do using this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path). You have to see version of python when you add the PATH variable.

Comment: you have to check path of folder which is you installed python.. it is gonna be like 'C:\Python27' and please examine link which is I give you first comment..

Comment: I tried alot, i added it to the path from enironment variables but still it is saying you have not any interpreter